# Sound coming from back wheel

Tags: road-bike, rear-wheel

After the crash I straightened back wheel, and cleaned and lubricated the chain, but now spinning the wheel causes sound as if there is something wrong with bearings.

Here is the video: https://streamable.com/fhb81d.

My bicycle model is Trek Domane AL2. What might be wrong with the bicycle? Should I try to disassemble the bearings and regrease them?

Not holding qr spindle spinning the unmounted wheel in the air: https://streamable.com/gnew8e

Holding qr spindle and putting wheel on a glass table which amplifies the sound: https://streamable.com/keu4xj

Holding qr spindle and holding wheel in the air: https://streamable.com/keu4xj

QR skewer removed and holding the wheel in the air:
https://streamable.com/42vtit

**Edit 1**
Went to bicycle shop. Confirmed that degreaser got into the bearings.

Comment: It does sound like something is not right but the free hub noise is masking any bearing noise. Post a video of the wheel being driven by the chain

Comment: If you think it is the bearings, you can take the rear wheel out of the bike, and turn the axle by hand. You can even hold the wheel around the axle, and spin it while holding it up. If the bearings are rough, you will feel the roughness as the axle turns. If this is a new bike, it doesn’t seem likely the bearings are bad, however.

Comment: Thanks! Bicycle is pretty new but it had a crash after which I straightened the back wheel and changed the oils. I will remove the wheel and check for noises. Thanks again!

Comment: I’@ŽilvinasRudžionis I'm really curious about what you mean by ‘change the oil’. Do you mean cleaning and re-lubricating the chain?

Comment: Yes, I washed bicycle with water and soap, applied degreaser, washed with water and soap and lubricated the chain.

Comment: Depending on the wheel's hub brand, this might have cartridge bearings or it might have cup and cone bearings.   One can't generally service cartridge bearings, they just get replaced.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the noise that you're concerned about (laptop speakers aren't great) however in your first video I note that the clear plastic chain/spoke guard is warped, possibly as a result of a still bent spoke or simple leftover from your crash. 
When the freehub is freewheeling is the guard rubbing on the largest rear cog?

Comment: @LamarLatrell previously it was but truing the wheel helped to solve this. I checked for bent spokes but they look fine to me. I also added more videos where it is easier to hear the sounds and qr spindle is not in a free spin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the wheel was impacted enough to require truing it’s plausible the hub was damaged. The axle might have been bent, bearings damaged or the freehub mechanism.

You can easily check for bearing problems. Take the wheel out, turn the axle manually. Feel for play or roughness in the bearings as the axle turns.

Hold the axle ends and spin the wheel, check for clicking or grinding noises. Hold the cassette and spin the wheel backwards, check for clicking coming from the freehub mechanism.

The nuts on the axle indicate you may have a cup and cone style hub which can be disassembled. I’d hesitate to disassemble a rear hub though as the bearing arrangements can be complicated.

Comment: I added a video where I am spinning the removed wheel. Maybe you could take a look ? Thanks!

Comment: @ŽilvinasRudžionis There’s nothing really obvious, nothing i could diagnose through a video. If the axle spins freely with no roughness I think your bearings are probably good. That does not rule out a problem with the free hub though.

Comment: @ŽilvinasRudžionis Argenti, in the video (i.e. the second video) the wheel is spinning on the qr spindle in your hands, the bearings are not turning. try again

Comment: @Swifty good catch

Comment: Added two more videos. It feel like there is some grinding and resistance against qr spindle (spinning wheel from time to time would rotate the qr spindle if I wouldn't be holding it) once wheel is spinning

Comment: @ŽilvinasRudžionis take the QR skewer out, I think it's just complicating your attempts at diagnosis. When in the frame the axle and skewer do not rotate or move against one another

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus removed QR skewer and added a new video: https://streamable.com/42vtit

Comment: @ŽilvinasRudžionis Yes there is a little clicking but it's impossible to tell if it's a bearing issue or the freehub through a video. It's possible your axle is slightly bent also.if the wheel received an impact and you had to true it.

Comment: As suggested in comments, what did you feel? Especially with QR skewer removed.

Comment: @LamarLatrell I felt that while wheel was spinning from time to time there was some roughness and grinding

Comment: Ok, then at least your bearings need attending to 